# EXCEL COUNTIFS() equivalent in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am needing the equivalent of `COUNTIFS()` note the `S` in Tableau.
I have found the logic for `COUNTIF` but not `COUNTIFS()`.

For example here is what I am doing in EXCEL but need to be doing this in Tableau instead.

The criteria is this.
Note the below NULL's are actually just a string value and not a true Null.

1. First column must not be NULL
2. 2nd column must be NULL
3. If both conditions are met count row.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the AND key word.

```
count(if not isnull([column1]) and isnull([column2]) then 1 end)
```

Comment: Thanks Bernardo. I actually already got what I needed and it was slightly different than this. We used `SUM(
IF not isnull([Col1])
and
isnull([Col2])
Then 1
END
)` But yours is just as good and probably slightly better.

Comment: You can also use sum(int(not is null(column1) and is null(column2)) since the function int() turns True to 1 and False to 0.